# VBA - Manually Print on Both Sides

Tags: vba, printing, ms-office

My printer doesn't support `Both Sides` when printing, but I can choose to `Manually Print on Both Sides` before printing the document.

I'd like to know if that's possible on Macro?

I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
ActiveDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, ManualDuplexPrint:=False
```

I also tried the below code but no luck.

```
Dim iTemp As Integer

ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1, PageType:=wdPrintOddPagesOnly
iTemp = MsgBox("Switch paper to continue", vbOKCancel, "PrintBothSides")
If iTemp = vbOK Then
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1, PageType:=wdPrintEvenPagesOnly
End If
```

Comment: *I tried the following code but it doesn't work.* Not a very useful statement. What exactly did you expect to happen, and what actually happened? The same with *I also tried the below code but no luck.*

Comment: Are you saying you want to print only the odd numbered pages, then you manually put the paper back into the printer and then you print the even-numbered pages?